# Sonicwall bulk DHCP reservation

Tags: dhcp, sonicwall

We are migrating over to using SonicWALL as our firewall from Microsoft Forefront TMG.

I have managed to export our DHCP Reservations from the DHCP Service running on our TMG box but want to avoid having to type them in by hand into the SonicWALL admin screens.

Anyone got any ideas how to bulk upload a list of reservations.  I dont mind doing abit of scripting if necessary :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the SonicOS-API. Check the below KB. Even when is for creating Address Object, it would be the same process with a different JSON Object

https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/adding-multiple-address-objects-using-sonicos-api/200524131217347/

```
{
  "dhcp_server": {
    "ipv4": {
      "scope": {
        "static": [
          {
            "ip": "string",
            "mac": "string",
            "enable": true,
            "name": "string",
            "lease_time": 0,
            "default_gateway": "string",
            "netmask": "string",
            "comment": "string",
            "domain_name": "string",
            "dns": {
              "server": {}
            },
            "wins": {
              "primary": "string",
              "secondary": "string"
            },
            "call_manager": {
              "primary": "string",
              "secondary": "string",
              "tertiary": "string"
            },
            "network_boot": {
              "next_server": "string",
              "boot_file": "string",
              "server_name": "string"
            },
            "generic_option": {},
            "always_send_option": true
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```